# Electron js + Axios xhr.js:120 Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"

Tags: node.js, axios, electron

Faced such a problem that I use axios together with electron and I need to send several requests to the server with different headers. I am setting these headers to axios, but when I try to send a request from electron, this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We're having the same issues. Now I'm using `fetch` temporarily. I hope they could fix this.